# Reducing Database Queries per Row in Django Admin for Non-ForeignKey Fields

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm working with Django Admin and facing a challenge related to database queries. In my ModelAdmin, I have multiple functions that fetch data from another model (App). However, this model is not directly related through a ForeignKey. Each function makes an individual query to the App model for each row in the admin list, which seems inefficient.

Here's an example to illustrate my current setup:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('data_from_app_a', 'data_from_app_b', ...)

    def data_from_app_a(self, obj):
        # Fetches and returns specific data from App model
        data_a = App.objects.get(app_no=obj.app_no).field_a
        return data_a

    def data_from_app_b(self, obj):
        # Fetches and returns different data from App model
        data_b = App.objects.get(app_no=obj.app_no).field_b
        return data_b
```

In this example, data_from_app_a and data_from_app_b are functions that query the App model separately for each row. I'm looking to reduce the number of these per-row queries.

Is there a way to aggregate or prefetch this data more efficiently in Django Admin when dealing with non-ForeignKey relationships?

Comment: Why don't you use a `ForeignKey`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a `ForeignKey`. You can let a `ForeignKey` refer to another *unique* field of a model, so not per se its primary key.

If your `App` model thus looks like:

```
class App(models.Model):
    app_no = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
    data_a = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    data_b = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

You can let your model refer to the `app_no` field instead:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    app = models.ForeignKey(App, to_field='app_no', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # …
```

and since we refer to `app_no`, if you use `my_model_object.app_id`, it will return the `app_no` of the `App`, not its primary key.